# Initialize function differently based on

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, prototype

I have a web page that can be called as a single stand-alone web page or as a pop-up window.

When called from a web page, there is no callback attached. When called from a pop-up, there is a callback attached.

How do I initialize this based on the nature of the page itself?

Here is an example (for brevity). Lets say, in that page, I have a self executing code at the end.

```
(function(){
     return {
         init: function(){
                   console.log("this is init");           
               }
     }
 })().init();
```

Now, I would like to pass callback as argument to above function while calling this page as popup. How to modify this code to accommodate that?

Comment: Use a URL fragment or querystring variable to identify where the call to the page originated.

Comment: By checking `window.opener`.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: I have made a bit more clearer by enhancing my original question.

Comment: I got this figured out. I basically assigned this to a variable and removed calling init function. Now I call init function based on page being stand-alone page and call init function within parent window when its pop up page. This finally got resolved for me. Thanks.